# Class operator[] does not return a lhv

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, visual-studio-2013

Consider this class:

```
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

template<typename T>
class Vector{
private:
    size_t      size_;
    vector<T>   items;

public:
    Vector(){ size_ = 0; }
    inline void clear(){ size_ = 0; }
    inline void push_back( const T item ){
        if( items.size() == size_ )
            items.push_back( item );
        else
            items[size_] = item;
        size_++;
    }
    inline const T& operator[](int i) const { return items[i]; }
    inline T& operator[](int i) { return items[i]; }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    Vector<bool> vec;
    vec.push_back( true );
    if( vec[0] )
        vec[0] = false;
}
```

When compiling with MSVS 2013 you get the following error for the non const operator[]: `error C2440: 'return' : cannot convert from 'std::_Vb_reference<std::_Wrap_alloc<std::allocator<char32_t>>>' to 'bool &'`

Changing the return statement in `return (T&)(items[i]);` results in a warning `warning C4238: nonstandard extension used : class rvalue used as lvalue`

The program runs (in debug mode) but the last statement does not change the value of `vec[0]` (as you should expect for a rhv).

What's wrong here?

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector_bool - `vector<bool>` is a weird beast.

Comment: `vector<bool>` isn't a container, it's a `bitset`. The committee intends to remove it from the standard soon

Comment: You don't need to mark functions that are defined inside the class definition as `inline`. That happens automatically.

Comment: Strange, very strange, both the "automatic conversion" to bitset as the planned removal of the standard. A bitset has a fixed size, here I need something with a variable size. Now I have to implement it with a vector<int> with values 0 and 1 or a list<bool> (but in my case I need subscripting, so no help). Why not just keep the vector<bool> as a container as is?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because [`std::vector<bool>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector_bool) is special, it's a space-efficient **specialization** of `std::vector` for the type `bool`. And `operator[]` won't return `bool&` or `const bool&`, but a proxy class representing a reference to a single `bool`.

> Exposes class `std::vector<bool>::reference` as a method of accessing individual bits. In particular, objects of this class are returned by `operator[]` by value.